# How to get distinct objects from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have an array with 3 objects but I only want the values which are distinct with specific object property `artist_name`. I tried using `map()` but wasn't able to achieve what I want. I have the following array.

```
"tracks": [
                "artist_0": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "artist_name": "Taylor Swift"
                 },
                "artist_1": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "artist_name": "Taylor Swift"
                 },

                "artist_2": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "artist_name": "Ed Sheeran"
                 },
        ],
```

and I want this

```
"tracks": [
                "artist_0": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "artist_name": "Taylor Swift"
                 },
                "artist_2": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "artist_name": "Ed Sheeran"
                 },
        ],
```

Comment: do you really have an array with properties?

Comment: you're probably looking for `reduce` rather than `map`

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah I do. I'm fetching this from an API.

Comment: what is the `key` you want for the object, can the key be `artist` object's `id`?

Comment: do you get the data as JSON?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes actually. but this tracks is also just a part from the bigger JSON object. but I have this track array into another variable. but I only want the distinct values with artist name.

Comment: really an array with properties? it is not possible to get this structure via a JSON. it is not parsable.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm editing the question and writing down the entire JSON object. so you can get the idea. but I just want tracks.

Comment: The problem Nina is trying to describe is that you say you have an array, and your shell is `"tracks": [ ... ]`, but the content (`...`) here looks only appropriate to an object (keys and values.  Are you sure you don't have `"tracks: { ... }`?  (That is, using curly braces for an object, not square ones for an array.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a simple function to pass to `filter`, which we configure using a key-generation function.  It might look like this:

```js
const byUnique = (fn, found = new Set()) => (x) => 
  ((key = fn(x)) => found.has(key) ? false : found. add (key))()

const artistId = ({artist: {id}}) => id

const tracks = [{id: 1, artist: {id: 1, artist_name: "Taylor Swift"}, album: {id: 1, album_name: "Fearless (Taylor's Version)"}, track_name: "Love Story", time: "00: 03: 49", genre: "POP"}, {id: 2, artist: {id: 1, artist_name: "Taylor Swift"}, album: {id: 1, album_name: "Fearless (Taylor's Version)"}, track_name: "You Belong With Me", time: "00: 03: 40", genre: "POP"}, {id: 4, artist: {id: 2, artist_name: "Ed Sheeran"}, album: {id: 2, album_name: "Divide"}, track_name: "Perfect", time: "00: 04: 23", genre: "POP"}]

console .log (
  tracks .filter (byUnique (artistId))
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

There are reasonable arguments to change it to this:

```js
const byUnique = (fn) => (found = new Set()) => (x) => 
  ((key = fn(x)) => found.has(key) ? false : found. add (key))()
```

and call it with an extra function invocation like this:

```js
tracks .filter (byUnique (artistId) ())
```

because that would let us use it like this:

```js
const byUniqueArtistId = byUnique (artistId)
// later
tracks .filter (byUniqueArtistId ())
```

retaining the function `byUniqueArtistId` for when we want it.

And of course you could also wrap the `filter` call into a function easily enough so that you could call `filterByUniqueArtistId (tracks)`.  But that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thank you so much. I really got what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you have an object with properties, you could filter the entries with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and create a new object.

```js
const
    tracks = { artist_0: { id: 1, atist_name: "Taylor Swift" }, artist_1: { id: 1, artist_name: "Taylor Swift" }, artist_2: { id: 2, artist_name: "Ed Sheeran" } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(tracks)
        .filter(
            (s => ([, { id }]) => !s.has(id) && s.add(id))
            (new Set)
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your `tracks` by reducing the entries. While reducing, you can generate a key to "ban" any keys you have already encountered.

```js
const data = {
  "tracks": {
    "artist_0": { "id": 1 , "artist_name": "Taylor Swift" },
    "artist_1": { "id": 1 , "artist_name": "Taylor Swift" },
    "artist_2": { "id": 2 , "artist_name": "Ed Sheeran"   }
  }
}

const filterUnique = (arr, keyFn) =>
  Object.entries(arr)
    .reduce((acc, [key, item]) => (id =>
      !acc.ban.has(id) ? {
        res: { ...acc.res, [key]: item },
        ban: acc.ban.add(id)
      } : acc)
    (keyFn(item)),
    { res: {}, ban: new Set })
  .res;

const uniqueData = {
  tracks: filterUnique(data.tracks, ({ id, artist_name }) => `${id}-${artist_name}`)
};

console.log(uniqueData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const myData = {
  tracks: {
    artist_0: { id: 1, artist_name: 'Taylor Swift' },
    artist_1: { id: 1, artist_name: 'Taylor Swift' },
    artist_2: { id: 2, artist_name: 'Ed Sheeran' }
  }
};

const deleteNonUnique = (data) => objectScan(['tracks.*.id'], {
  filterFn: ({ value, context, gparent, gproperty }) => {
    if (context.has(value)) {
      delete gparent[gproperty];
    }
    context.add(value);
  },
  reverse: false
})(data, new Set());

console.log(deleteNonUnique(myData));
// => Set(2) { 1, 2 }

console.log(myData);
/* => {
  tracks: {
    artist_0: { id: 1, artist_name: 'Taylor Swift' },
    artist_2: { id: 2, artist_name: 'Ed Sheeran' }
  }
} */
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

may be my code would took extra space but i tried to more simplify so you can know behind the scenes

```
const obj = {
    artist_0: {
        id: 1,
        artist_name: 'Taylor Swift',
    },
    artist_1: {
        id: 1,
        artist_name: 'Taylor Swift',
    },

    artist_2: {
        id: 2,
        artist_name: 'Ed Sheeran',
    },
};

const unique = {};
const unique_id = [];

for (const val in obj) {
    if (typeof unique[val] == 'undefined' && unique_id.includes(obj[val].id) == false) {
        unique[val] = obj[val];
        unique_id.push(unique[val].id);
    }
}

console.log(unique);
```

first of all we have defined an object with duplicate values.
than we defined an empty unique object and an empty unique_id array than we are iterating on our main object and checking whether that key exist or not in unique object and also checking whether id of an object is in or not in our unique_id array if our unique array not include that id and also our unique object not include that key than we are assigning it to our unique object and push id to unique_id array so it can track all the previous id then we are showing our unique array

Answer (score 0):

In case you were googling this question (like me) and aren't satisfied. Here is what I think you are trying to do and the shortest solution I came up with (just ONE line of code for the function itself):

```js
arr_of_objs = [{key:1},{key:2},{key:2},{key:3},{key:3},{key:3}];
// 'key' values: 1,2,2,3,3,3

distinct_by_prop = arr_of_objs.filter((x, i, a) => a.findIndex(y => x.key === y.key) == i);
// output: [{key:1},{key:2},{key:3}]

console.log(distinct_by_prop);
```

You can also use .findLastIndex instead of .findIndex. It works the same in this example, but keeps the last instance of the obj with the duplicate key value instead of the first. This could be beneficial in case your array of objects is sorted in a specific way (i.e.: Later entries might be chronologically more up to date).

Please note: While I think this is the nicest way to do it... Performance-wise in extremely huge datasets (like >10M entries), it might be better to use for loops, as most browsers still handle them faster as of now.